# extract data before and after <br> tag using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

How to extract text before and after 
 tag using selenium and xpath in JAVA.
I have following code

```
<tr>
 <td>
   This is my amount
   <br> 
   $3.2
 </td>
<tr>
```

I want result like "This is my amount"  "$3.2" each field in a column of table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `getText()` which will return entire element text. For `<Br>` it will have line break in returning text so you can spilt text by `'\n'` if want each line text.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly, try this: `String resultText = new WebDriverWait(driver(),5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("{XPATH for your tag<td>}"))).getText().replaceAll("\n"," ");`